Looking for a data.table´s value in another data.table and assign it
I have a big data.table DT with {x, status, letter, z}. I have another data.table Values with {idx, idz}, with idx sorted; then, there will always be DT$x  in  DTValues.
For example:
DT <- data.table(z=0, 
                 x=35:39, 
                 status=c(0,0,1,0,1) , 
                 letter = c("a","b","a","a","b"))
DT


Values <- data.table(xid =33:39,  
                     idz=rnorm(7))
Values


I  look for the DT$x  in  Values and update DT$z, when DT$status=0 and DTletter="a".
My solution was:
DT[DT$status==0 & letter=="a", 
    z:= Values$idz[DT$x[DT$status==0 & DT$letter=="a"]- 32 ] ]

DT


I also tried
DT[DT$status==0 & letter=="a", 
    z:= Values[DT[DT$status==0 & DT$letter=="a"], .(idz), on="x"] ]) 

but this is not so fast.
Is there a more elegant and faster way to do this?

@M, if no keys are present, on-argument is needed.  DT[Values, z  := ifelse(status == 0 & letter == "a", idz, z), on = .(x = xid)]
